# jQuery fadeIn() between if and else

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, fadein

I want to fade between different images which are loaded when different things happen. I created some if, else rules and thought I can tell jQuery with the `fadeIn()` to fade in every new image. But it's not working and I don't know why. 
I think it's a super little code thing I can't figure out. Hope you guys can help me!

Here is my code so far:

```
if(count == 1){
    $('.star').html('<img src="' + stern1 + '">').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
} else if (count == 2){
    $('.star').html('<img src="' + stern2 + '">').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
} else if(count == 3){
    $('.star').html('<img src="' + stern3 + '">').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
} else if(count == 4){
    $('.star').html('<img src="' + stern4 + '">').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
} else if(count == 5) {
    $('.star').html('<img src="' + stern5 + '">').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    $('.star').html('<img src="' + stern1 + '">').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: I think you will need to create a demo or show more of the relevant source code for anyone to find the problem. Where is `count` and `stern1-5` coming from and where are those defines? Please open your browser console to check for error reports.

Comment: does ".star. have the style attribute of display:none ?  Can you post the code related to that class.

Comment: also the code where you are getting the count might be useful

Comment: Here you go: jsfiddle.net/8L6g2uej

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes is:

> Insert the content in your html

So it displays the content always, your effort is not showing like delay and fadeIn.

Please try the following:

```
$('.star').html('<img src="' + stern1 + '">').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: If I add the `hide()` function, it disappears before it fades it. But it fades!  
Check this fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/8L6g2uej

Comment: @dwd0tcom If you use this code "$('.star').html('<img src="' + stern1 + '">').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');", then the image is not shown initially after that your fadeIn property works perfectly. Please check and let me know.